# c# mvc helper extension Html.DisplayFor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, extension-methods, displayfor

Hours later.  Interneting later.  Hair pulling later.

Prs_Role_ID_Deleted is an int .

In my Details.cshtml, I am trying to have it output a "" (empty string) if the value of model.Prs_Role_ID_Deleted = 0 (zeri).

The problem is I am unable unable to get the value of model => model.Prs_Role_ID_Deleted .
I can get the property name.
I can get the model.Prs_Role_ID_Deleted .

I am unable to get the value of model.Prs_Role_ID_Deleted which should equal 22.

```
@Html.ZZZ(model => model.Prs_Role_ID_Deleted)


public static MvcHtmlString ZZZ<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression)
{
    var id = helper.ViewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldId(ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression));
    return "whatever";
}
```

I am beginning to think it is not possible to ascertain the value.

---

Thanks SLaks.  That was the solution.

Posting solution for other developers.

AFTER SLaks advice

```
@Html.DisplayForWithID_ZeroIsBlank(model => model.Prs_Role_ID_Deleted, "span")
<dd><span id="Prs_Role_ID_Deleted"></span></dd>

public static MvcHtmlString DisplayForWithID_ZeroIsBlank<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression, string wrapperTag = "span")
{
    var id = helper.ViewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldId(ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression));
    TModel model = (TModel)helper.ViewContext.ViewData.ModelMetadata.Model;
    var ctlValue = expression.Compile()(helper.ViewData.Model);
    string OutputValue = "Silly developer. This only works for int.";
    Type type = ctlValue.GetType();
    if (type.Equals(typeof(int)))
    {
        string s = ctlValue.ToString().Trim();
        if (ctlValue == null || ctlValue.ToString().Trim() == "0")
        {
            OutputValue = "";
        }
        else
        {
            OutputValue = ctlValue.ToString();
        }
    }
    return MvcHtmlString.Create(string.Format("<{0} id=\"{1}\">{2}</{0}>", wrapperTag, id, OutputValue, helper.DisplayFor(expression)));
}
```

Comment: why not create a view model and do all your conversions there?

Comment: Fran, the way I think MVC works is that the "model" only contains the model of pure data.  Formatting for output is either in the cshtml, JS, or helper extension.  For me, combining output format would be like putting a hamburger on the same plate as ice cream.  Yes it can be done but it would get real sloppy.

Comment: a view model has nothing to do with formatting output,  the view model contains the data items for the page.  what exactly is pure data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to compile the expression to a delegate, then call it on the model:

```
expression.Compile()(helper.ViewData.Model);
```